# Epson BX635FWD Black print poor

Tags: printing, printer, ink

I have an unusual problem in that if I print a page of black text using the 'Fast' print configuration, then I get a poor print on every 6th line of text. If I print using one of the 'Quality' settings the the print is fine. It only happens when I print using the black ink. The three colours are fine. I use compatible cartridges. I've tried cleaning the nozzles, but this doesn't make any difference. I've changed the black cartridge 3 times, because the printer randomly decided that it didn't recognise it.
I'm wondering if there is a problem with the firmware / hardware that controls the black ink.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: doesn't answer your question, but… After years of similar [& different, yet many] issues with inkjets, I finally threw away my last one & bought a laser. 10 years later & I'm still on the first ink cartridges that came with it. Never looked back. [Though my usage is light & I don't try to print 'quality photographs' with it.]

Comment: You don't indicate whether the cartridges contain the printhead like some HP printers, or the cartridges are just ink.  If they are just ink, you probably have a persistent clog in the printhead that the print cycle can't clean.  If the printhead is removable, you can probably clean it by soaking in hot distilled water or isopropyl alcohol (and use an ultrasonic cleaner if you have one).  If the printhead is on the cartridge, try cleaning the electrical contacts to the cartridge with isopropyl alcohol on a swab.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with an Epson Workforce WF-2630. I used the head cleaning program built into the printer about ten times in a row, alternating with the printer test. Eventually I noticed black lines begin to appear again and then after one clean it suddenly went back to normal.

NB - I have been using non-standard ink cartridges.